# Reduce SOQL Queries

Tags: apex, soql, loop, governorlimits, for

For every Account in AccountList, I need to make 2 different callouts - when a contact exists and 2nd when no contact exists.

How can I reduce the no of SOQL queries in the below code.

```
for(Account acc:accList){
  List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id from Contact WHERE AccountId=:acc.Id];
  if(conList!=null && conList.size()>0){
     for(Contact con:conList){
        //do a callout
     }
  }
  else{
     //no contact
     //do a different callout
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you query the linked Contacts at the same time you are querying for Accounts like below?

```
 List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, (Select Id From Contacts) From Account];

 for(Account a : accounts)
 {
     if(a.Contacts.size() != 0){
         for(Contact c : a.Contacts) {
             //do a callout
         }
     }
     else
     {
        //do something else
     }
 }
```

OR

Get all of the contacts for all accounts in accList at once:

```
 List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id, AccountId From Contact Where AccountId IN :accList];


 for(Account a : accList)
 {
     Boolean hasContacts = false;
     for(Integer i = 0; i<contacts.size(); i++)
     {
         Contact c = contacts[i];

         if(c.AccountId == a.Id)
         {
             hasContacts = true;        
             //do a callout

             //remove the contact from list so we don't iterate through it again
             contacts.remove(i--);
         }
     }

     if(hasContacts == false)
     {
         //account doesn't have contacts, do something else
     }
 }
```

Comment: the 2nd option doesn't work, because I cannot differentiate Accounts without contacts.

Comment: Sure you can, check my edit.

Comment: I made additional edit where I changed the `for` loop for `contacts` and I remove the processed `contact` from the list so the code doesn't have to iterate through it again. Let me know if this helps!